# Apple Watch simple "Modular Large" complication not showing in customize screen unless I enable all other complications too

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

I am testing and able to reproduce this in a very simple app. I am following the WWDC 2015 video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/209/

Another tutorial which uses the same info is: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/watchkit-2-complications/

Just like the WWDC video, I want my app to only provide a `CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody` complication. So in my extension's target general settings, I have enabled ONLY `Modular Large`.

[image]

For a simple test, I only added the code for the placeholders:

```
- (void)getLocalizableSampleTemplateForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTemplate * __nullable complicationTemplate))handler {
    // This method will be called once per supported complication, and the results will be cached
    NSLog(@"getLocalizableSampleTemplateForComplication: %ld",(long)complication.family);

    if (complication.family==CLKComplicationFamilyModularLarge) {
        CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody *template = [[CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody alloc] init];
        template.headerTextProvider=[CLKSimpleTextProvider textProviderWithText:@"Date"];
        template.body1TextProvider=[CLKSimpleTextProvider textProviderWithText:@"Class"];
        template.body2TextProvider=[CLKSimpleTextProvider textProviderWithText:@"Location"];
        handler(template);
    } else {
        handler(nil);
    }
}
```

After this, I deleted and even reseted both the iPhone and Watch simulator. Then ran the app. In the Watch's customize screen for `Infograph Modular` watch face, I don't see my app available.

[image]

An interesting thing (bug???) I noticed is that if I go to the extension's general settings and enable all the complications, then it shows up.

[image]

But I don't want to provide other types of complications. I only want to provide Modular Large for my app. Is this a bug?

Another thing I noticed is that the placeholder shows -------- instead of my provided TextProvider templates. Is this another bug?

I have reset the simulator, deleted my app from watch and iPhone many times to no solution. After resetting, my `NSLog` for `getLocalizableSampleTemplateForComplication` does print however the complication doesn't appear in the customize screen.

Comment: This doesn't help resolve your issue, but I'm also running into this... my complication (Graphic Corner) doesn't appear in the Customize screen and flashes between the complication graphic and the placeholder name of my app during use unless I enable all of the possible complication types in WatchKit Extension > General > Complications Configuration.

Comment: @Pranoy C - i m running into the same issue. let us know if u find a solution.

Comment: Maybe it is late but lets try to save someone some time. You are using wrong complication family. 
Instead of `CLKComplicationFamilyModularLarge` you should use `CLKComplicationFamilyGraphicRectangular`

Comment: why can't he use family modular large?

Answer (score -1):

The complication family is `CLKComplicationFamilyGraphicRectangular` for the above watch face. So use that for updating values and placeholder text